# Find $k$ s.t. $kx^2+4$, $k^2-x^2$ orthogonal

Tags: calculus

It is a problem I encounter but I don't know what it means. There are two functions $kx^2+4$,$k^2-x^2$, it asks me to find $k$ st. two graphs are orthogonal. I actually don't know what the graph orthogonality means

Comment: It is probably about finding a point at which the curves intersect and such that the tangents are perpenticular.

Comment: @polmath Derivatives are, at this level, not vectors, but real values.

Comment: Just edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what level you are at.  In sophomore or junior, it would probably mean $\int_a^b(kx^2+4)(k^2-x^2)dx=0$, for some values of $a$ and $b$, for example $a=0$ and $b=1$.

In calculus 101, I think it means that, at the two points they intersect, the tangents are at right-angles.  So find the points of intersection; find the slope of each function at those points, and when does $f_1'(x_1)f_2'(x_1)=-1, f_1'(x_2)f_2'(x_2)=-1$?

Comment: I am doing GRE sub math problem, so I think it is more likely to be the second one.